# Elasticsearch range aggregation ignores negative values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to bucket a range aggregation and achieve the following buckets:

```
<=0 - 0 including negative numbers
>=1 - 1 and above
```

field type = Integer

Query:

```json
GET _search
{
 "aggs": {
    "stock_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "field": "Facets_Integer_Stock",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 0
          },
          {
            "from": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping for field `Facets_Integer_Stock` :

```
"Facets_Integer_Stock" : {
   "type" : "integer"
},
```

I'm expecting 2 counts in the first bucket <0. It should include the hits with `-1` and `0`.

Response

```
{
  "took" : 26,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 8,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "stock_ranges" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "*-0.0",
          "to" : 0.0,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "1.0-*",
          "from" : 1.0,
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what results do you get?

Comment: @Val I've updated the question with the mapping and results.

Comment: I've found the issue.  I misread the `to` definition. I included the value of `to`, while it  excludes the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `range` aggregation, `to` is always exclusive, you should use `lte` and `gte` instead:

```
GET _search
{
 "aggs": {
    "stock_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "field": "Facets_Integer_Stock",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "lte": 0
          },
          {
            "gte": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## To solve

```json
POST /_bulk/
{"index":{"_index":"72376077"}}
{"data": -1}
{"index":{"_index":"72376077"}}
{"data":-2}
{"index":{"_index":"72376077"}}
{"data":0}
{"index":{"_index":"72376077"}}
{"data":1}
{"index":{"_index":"72376077"}}
{"data":2}

GET /72376077/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "stock_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "field": "data",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 0.1
          },
          {
            "from": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It give those buckets:

```json
{
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "*-0.1",
      "to": 0.0,
      "doc_count": 3
    },
    {
      "key": "1.0-*",
      "from": 1.0,
      "doc_count": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Which seems absolutely fine ?

Comment: This is not the correct answer as the `0` value is not counted (first bucket should be 3), since `to` is exclusive

Comment: I dammm indeed I miss read

Comment: You can use `to: 0.1` or preferably as in my answer use `lte: 0` which is more correct

Comment: Well, running `lte` search query on `8.1` does not work ... I am getting an error. maybe I am doing something wrong, but indeed your request is much more cleaner.

Comment: Hmm, you're right actually, `lte` is no more available in ES8, sorry about that

Comment: `"reason" : "[9:13] [range] unknown field [lte]"` using your query below or mine (swapping the from to for lte gte), and I don't see any mention of it in the documentation .... I may have read a bit to fast let me check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245038/discussion-between-paulo-and-val).

Comment: So the only option is to use `to: 0.1`, if you make that change then this is the right answer and I'll delete mine. Good catch!

Comment: I think I did, but let's keep both ! I ll just specify the version

Comment: No, actually the `range` aggregation never supported `lte/gte` and with reason, otherwise it would be very easy to count a document in two different buckets, which doesn't make sense for an aggregation that's supposed to partition the data.

Comment: Well, while a I agree `from` `to` makes it easier, I feel it could still be usefull for this feature to exist